# SELECT Sql Query joins the same table twice

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables like below
table 1:emp

```
Emp ID   SupervisorID
001      005
002      001
003      004
004      005
```

table 2:empdetails

```
ID       Name
001      John
002      Krish
003      Ramesh
004      Smith
005      Ranga
```

I need a sql query to display ID name from table 1 in two columns Employee and its Supervisor as shows result below

Result:

```
Emp     Supervisor
John    ranga
Krish   John
Ramesh  Smith
Smith   prasad
```

Comment: This is not even a question. It is just a request for someone else to do it for you. What have you tried? In any event just look in the manual under `JOIN`

Comment: Look into the use of table aliases in queries.

Answer (score 5):

Try with following query:

```
SELECT  ed1.Name AS 'ID',ed2.Name AS 'Name'  FROM emp e 
       JOIN empdetails ed1 ON e.EmpID=ed1.ID 
       JOIN empdetails ed2 ON e.SupervisorID=ed2.ID
```

It will take the result from `emp` table and try to get join with `empdetails`....

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly simple to join the same table twice: just use different table aliases to distinguish the instances.  In the following example I use an outer join to get the supervisor name, as every employee may not have a supervisor (there ought to be one person in the hierarchy, the ultimate boss, who doesn't have one).

```
select ed.name  as emp_name
       , sup.name as supervisor
from emp e         
    inner join empdetails ed on ( e.id = ed.id )
    left join empdetails sup on ( e.supervisorid = sup.id )
```